# CTimeStampBehaviour for setting create_time and update_time resetting create_time with afterFind()

Tags: php, datetime, yii, yii-behaviour

I am using CTimeStampBehaviour for setting create_time and update_time resetting create_time with afterFind() in model, Basically I am setting the format of date to be displayed on the front end. But this does not work as create_time is sent 0000-00-00 00:00:00 on using model's afterFind(). It works fine when I comment afterFind() in model.

I have used this function in my model:

```
public function behaviors(){
return array(
    'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
        'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
        'createAttribute' => 'create_time',
        'updateAttribute' => 'update_time',
        'setUpdateOnCreate'=> true,
    )
);
}
```

I have seen the documentation on CTimeStampBehavior class on yii site, it has a reference to afterFind() inheritence but does not suggest how to use it. I am using afterFind() in model like this:

```
protected function afterFind() {
parent::afterFind();
$this->create_time = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(
        CDateTimeParser::parse(
            $this->create_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
        ), 'short', 'short'
    );
return true;
}
```

Can anyone suggest why the create_time is being zero filled when using afterFind()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_time` will be zero filled when you save the model after loading it and afterFind() changed the value of `create_time` to a formatted date.
This is because when you save your model now your are trying to send the formatted value to the database which does not understand the format and set the value to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

When you implement an `afterFind()` method to change values format, you have to implement a `beforeSave()` method to set the value back to a format that can be understood by the database.

It is generally a bad idea to format values directly on the model. When you are doing strict MVC it is the job of the View to format your Date correctly.

Comment: public function beforeSave() {
 if ($this->isNewRecord)
     $this->cdate = new CDbExpression('NOW()');

 $this->mdate = new CDbExpression('NOW()');

 return parent::beforeSave();
    }

    protected function afterFind() {

 $this->cdate = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(
   CDateTimeParser::parse(
    $this->cdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
   ), 'short', 'short'

  );

 $this->mdate = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(
   CDateTimeParser::parse(
    $this->mdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
   ), 'short', 'short'

  );

 return parent::afterFind();
    }

Comment: Hi @cebe,

I have added the code for beforeSave() as well. but the problem is same.

Please help!

Comment: You have to reset all values you changed in afterFind to a database readable format when you do this kind of transformation.

Database can not understand "20. January 2013" you have to format that back to "2013-01-20".

BUT you should take my last sentence serious. do not do it this way, use for example CFormatter to display date in view.